# Error 'A column name 'N' already belongs to this data table' when uploading flat file

Tags: sql-server, import, flat-file

I am trying to upload a flat file (CSV) by using the 'Import Flat File' option in SSMS v17.9.1. But after I select the file that is to be uploaded and click next, an error appears that says:

> A column name 'N' already belongs to this data table.

There are no duplicate columns present in the table.

Can someone please tell me why this error is occurring or how to go around this issue?

Comment: Have you tried "Import Data" rather than "Import Flat File"? - https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/import-csv-file-into-sql-server-using-sql-server-management-studio/

Comment: I tried that but it stops after some time not showing what the error is. In the preview the columns look fine. Not sure what is going wrong. I used to upload file of size 5 gb before, now trying 20 gb file (it is a file with same number of columns only more rows), could the size be causing the issue. I know for sure that ssms has the space for a large file?

Comment: No, I don't think the size is the issue from what I've read, as there are articles on DBA Stack Overflow importing 48GB files.  They do talk about using Powershell to do it, I don't know if that is an option for you - https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/186121/import-data-from-48-gb-csv-file-to-sql-server

Comment: Do you happen to know the possible cause for this error?

Comment: It sounds like you have 2 (or more) columns with the name `N` in your CSV file.

Comment: There are no columns named 'N' in the csv file. There are multiple flag columns that take values N/Y but they have different column names.

Comment: I think ssms might be reading the second row in the csv file as the header, is there a way to change the settings to make it read the first row as headers? Cannot seem to have that in 'Import flat file' option?

Comment: Seems you've not set the correct row delimiter. You need to define the row delimiter correctly and then it knows where the first "row" ends.

Comment: by default it is set to LF and it is a comma separated file. Does that seem okay

Comment: Is there a way to change the settings to make SQL Server read the first row as column names when importing dlat file?

Comment: When you choose a data source you get an option Header Rows to Skip

Comment: I am using SSMS 17.9.1. Cannot see that option. Would you be able to tell me where to locate it?